# Comparing statistics (correlation, RMS, bias, error, etc)

Tags: correlation, p-value, standard-error, bias

When comparing the errors and biases between various deterministic model forecasts to observations, how can I tell which differences are significant?

Specifically: I'm running air quality forecasts (hindcasts) in models of different resolutions, lets say models A and B.  I compare the results of these forecasts to observations by generating error and bias (for either each timestep, but generally for the entire simulation period) statistics for each species (ozone, NO, NO<sub>2</sub>, etc.)

These models are running forecasts with the same input data, and the same physics.  The only difference is the resolution.  So the output of these models wouldn't be independent.

For some species model A will have a much better bias or error, but sometimes it won't.  Is there a way to determine which biases or errors are significant? (i.e. run a *p*-test?)

Right now, when I see large differences in how good the errors or biases are, I interpret that as one model is performing better under these conditions than the other, but when the results are close, I'm just curious if the difference is probably just noise - but my threshold for such a judgement is extremely fuzzy right now.

Comment: It is counterproductive (or worse, entirely misleading) to generate lots of statistics and ask "are these significant."  Instead, turn around and ask "what can these data tell me about what I'm interested in and how reliable is the information they give me about that?"  This practice will help you identify what the relevant statistics and tests might be.

Comment: I can understand where this can be misused, but surely when presented with a vector of mean biases from various models that are all close in value, there must be a way to distinguish which ones are significantly different, and which ones are likely the product of noise.

Comment: That might depend on what a "mean bias" is and how it's calculated--but that doesn't seem to be what your question is asking.  It's currently much broader than that.  It's also not clear what "independent model values" means, given that any set of values computed from a single sample would usually be *dependent*, at least if the sample is viewed probabilistically.  Would it be possible to pose your question less abstractly so that readers could get a sense of context and objectives?

Comment: I do agree that the question is too broad right now.  Right now I'm too inexperienced with this to even ask a question well.  I'll do my best tonight to re-write it.  About the independence of the data, I was uncertain about that.  My observation data is air quality concentrations at various monitoring stations in an area.  Each "model" is really the same model but with different settings.  So, while they're run independently, I would expect them to all behave similarly.  In this setup, can I not consider the model output data independent?

Comment: You might find it helpful to think of a hierarchy of chance events.  The first is the chance that intervenes in producing the concentrations.  It models variation over time and space as well as the entire sampling and analytical process.  The second is any chance that you consider to underlie differences in model results, *conditional* on a given dataset.  Although the latter may be conditionally independent, they will not be independent from one dataset to the next. If your interest lies in making inferences from the data, testing differences in model results seems unlikely to be meaningful.